# Imported VM fail to generate IP

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I've downloaded a few VMs from vulnhub with the intention of honing my pentesting skills against them. In all the download pages, the VMs are supposed to generate their own IP addresses. However, running the following command,`VBoxManage guestproperty get vm "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/0/V4/IP"`
yields "no value set!".

I tried setting it to something within my network (as far as I understand, this should be what is done automatically), but this does not work. Pinging the new address results in 100% packet loss.

Am I checking the wrong values? Is there something that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance